# how to make scalar product with blas in c

Tags: c, blas

I'm new to BLAS and I've tried reading the documentation concerning said subject. So far I'm trying to implement a simple scalar product.

```
double x[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
double coeff = 4.323;
int one = 1;
int n = 3;
cblas_dscal(n, coeff, x, one);
printf("pass");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%lf" ,x[i]);
}
```

I used the header cblas.h. Upon compiling with the command  gcc -o exec code.c -lblas
I receive no errors. When I launch the executable nothing appears not even the "pass" which is problematic. Could anyone give any tips on how to save me? ;-;

ps: I'm really sorry if the question isn't well formulated this is my first question on stackoverflow so if you have any tips on how to formulate my questions better I would be grateful :)

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. If you still need help, [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that we can copy and run ourselves.

Comment: The code looks fine to me... try: `printf("pass");` --> `printf("pass\n");` Still no output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I launch the executable nothing appears not even the "pass" which is problematic.

Use `fflush(stdout)` after a `printf` call (or use `fprintf(stdout, ...)` instead of `printf`.)

Sometimes, programs can crash before they are able to flush the print buffer to STDOUT.  Using `fflush` or `fprintf` will force a flush directly after printing, which is useful for debugging issues like this (when you don't want to use a full debugger).

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't print out the "pass" string.

Comment: Put another print statement before the `cblas_dscal` call.  If that displays, then something about your blas call is wonky.

Comment: Ah I just derped out and realised that earlier in my code I forgot to update a variable in a while loop ;-;. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: sorry for bothering a  bit more but do you know what the "one" statement in the blas call might mean?

Comment: lol, I think you can handle that one yourself!  Look two lines above the `blas` call in the example code you posted.